# React redux removing multiple objects from list

Tags: redux, react-redux

I just started with react-redux and so far I'm loving it. I have a problem tho removing all objects from array that match a groupid.

```
deleteManyProducts: (state, action) => {
     state.list.map((val, i)=>{
          if(val.groupid === action.payload.groupid) {
                state.list.splice(i,1)
          }   
     })
}
```

I first tested it with 3 objects in array and it removed first two. Than I tested it with 4 objects and it also removed first two and left last two.
Finally I tested with 5 objects and it removed first three and left last two.

I checked couple of times that the groupid matches and it does match with all objects I use.
I tried this piece of code also but it doesn't work at all:

```
deleteManyProducts: (state, action) => {
     state.list.filter(val=>val.groupid !== action.payload.groupid)
}
```

However when I dispatch the same action again on remaining objects it just removes the one I selected for removal. I don't understand why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The filter() or map() method - creates a new array

so you can do `state.list = state.list.filter(...)`

but in Redux you can't send the same state... so you should use shallow copy or deep copy for that.

```
deleteManyProducts: (state, action) => {
     const copy = {...state};
     copy.list = state.list.filter(val=>val.groupid !== action.payload.groupid);
     return copy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I will accept your answer in 10 min cause it won't allow me to do it right away :)

Comment: Thanks! Don't rush, there may be smarter answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
const list = state.list.filter(val => val.groupid !== action.payload.groupid);
state.list = [...list];
```

`filter` & `map` both returns new array, even though you are using `splice` on original array. That's not a proper way to use them in this case.